# Performance out of windows C# chart controls?

Tags: c#, performance, optimization, charts

Has any one had any luck with getting good performance out of the built in c# chart running in real time?

I have made a chart with 3 charting areas and 9 series which are all the fast line type. I update in real time points to the series and shift the graphs over once 7 seconds of data has been graphed. All this works fine, however the rate that my graphs update is horribly slow. Sometimes it can take almost a second for the data being fed in to be shown in the graph (and many times i wonder if it is accurately updating my graph with my data since it is so slow and the data changes can be so fast).

I have tried using mychart.Series.SuspendUpdates(), Series.ResumeUpdates(), and Series.Invalidate() as i saw on different posting with no noticeable results.

If anyone could share some insight about ways to optimize I would be truly gracious.( and cutting the number data points is not a valid optimization )

Thanks in advance
OCV

Comment: Just as any perf question goes, do you know which method is the costliest?  Have you tried a profiler?

Comment: Is this all going on in one thread, or do you have a data handler and a drawing thread?

Comment: I was planning on writing a profiler and testing where the bottlenecks are if i get any complaints on the performance of the graph from customers. I am pretty sure most my time is being spent during the draw calls, I have had the data portion of the code working in a program using 3d graphics to represent the data and i get frame rates of 200fps+ so i know that the data is getting calculated and coming in at a reasonable rate.

Comment: As for threading it is all taking place on one thread however i was contemplating adding a thread. Id like to know if this would add a good deal of perf first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If external libraries is an option, ZedGraph worked great for me when displaying data at 10ms intervals (up to 8 series).

If you really must use the built-in C#, I think you might prevent blocking by separating drawing a data into separate threads.